# Could Not Find The Main Class. Program Will Exit. Error From Eclipse

Tags: java

All previous post for this topic didn't help me. I am trying to execute a simple Hello World program & getting error `"Coluld Not Find The Main Class. Program Will Exit"`. Please find my code below

```
package java.examples;

public class Hello_World {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

I am using Eclipse Indigo SR2 on a 64bit Windows 7 operating system with JDK 1.6.0_16.

Comment: How are you trying to run it?  From the command line, or through Eclipse?

Comment: Nothing you've said so far indicates any kind of problem. All anybody could do for you is enumerate all the troubleshooting steps. Use Google instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put classes in the `java.` package, or in any of the sub-packages under `java.`.  This protects the core language from being extended in ways that could break the core language.

Use "refactoring" to move the class into a different package, such as `org.yourname`.  Then you can select the file from the menu, and "run as file", or set the class to be the "main" class of the project and run by pressing the launcher button in the menu button bar.

The reason the error is obscure (and seems to be wrong) is because you can compile classes in `java` packages and sub-packages; however, the class loader will refuse to load then when the JVM is running.  As such, it seems that the class is ok, until you attempt to run it.  A rename of the package should fix most of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

This will having nothing to do with your actual code. Instead you need to set the main class for your project. I personally use netbeans so I'm not sure if these steps will help.

But I right click on my project, go to properties. Then Run, and set the main class to my main method.